# GIT: "fatal: unable to write new_index file" while commit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

When I try to commit changes to local repo, I have got following message:
    fatal: unable to write new_index file

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As this [thread illustrates](http://luhman.org/blog/2010/04/05/git-fatal-unable-write-newindex-file), this is usually a disk space issue:

```
$ git status
fatal: unable to write new_index file
```

> One cause of this that I found was that my file system had run out of space.
>   Finding large directories with something like the following helped clean up some log files that had run wild :

```
$ du -h / | grep ^[0-9.]*G
```

---

Note: you can also see it for

- a [resource issue](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/newsLists/news.eclipse.egit/msg00125.html) with msysgit and Egit (Git for Eclipse):

> Problem still remained so I ran File Monitor from Sysinternals Suite.
>   It seems that Eclipse is accessing index file constantly and blocks command line git

- for a [classic anti-virus issue](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/browse_thread/thread/64a167eaf44787f7/2811000e6954f478):

> Yeah, looks like Windows Defender strikes again. I always forget to disable that damn thing. I can't believe how broken it is. Destroys Blu-ray playback at home, breaks Git at work...

Comment: +1 for the Windows Defender portion! http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-Windows-Defender-on-or-off did the trick

Comment: also you can change the permissions (in windows) on the .git folder by uncheking the read-only

Comment: That's why AV like MSE lets you select folders not to monitor.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using TortoiseGit, this error (or more recently: *error: Unable to write index.*) is very likely caused by having **TortoiseGit icon overlays** enabled. To disable icon overlays, go to:

**TortoiseGit > Settings > Icon Overlays**

and set **Status cache** to **None**. This may be fixed in a future version of TortoiseGit, but for now it seems to be common.

Comment: This was the cause of the issue for me. Thanks much.

Comment: This was the cause in my case too. Thanks for posting this answer.

Comment: Yup, this was it for me - sort of. I had to actually kill the `TGitCache.exe` process, but that did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

I was getting the same error while I was merging a git repo that was sshfs mounted. There was no shortage of space anywhere.

In my case the solution was to add an -o workaround=rename option to the sshfs mount command.

Like so:
sshfs -o idmap=user -o uid=[lokal uid] -o gid=[lokal gid] -o workaround=rename [host]: [mountpoint]

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem. In my case above solutions didn't work.

The reason behind this error is that the file `.git/index` was corrupted for some unknown reason. I just renamed the file to something else and run the  'git add .' command from git bash and it worked.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This did the trick for me.  But instead of running `git add .`, I ran `git reset`, which re-generated the index file without unnecessarily adding all changes everything to the staging area.  I had SourceTree opened to the repo over an SSHFS mount while simultaneously interacting with it via the terminal; something there may have caused the file to get corrupted.

Answer (score 4):

I have found solution. Just need to free some disk space.

Comment: I was writing the same thing;)

Answer (score 4):

For me it was a file locking issue.

To solve it I:

1. Copied the index file (located in the hidden ".git" folder)
2. Deleted the original
3. Renamed the copy back to 'index'

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I have followed every solution here and none of them worked. I have no shortage of disk space, I have disabled Windows Defender, disabled icon overlays and whatnot. I had tons of files to import and maybe this was causing the problem (I had `boost` libraries among other things).

I simply opened "Git Bash" and issued a number of `git add` and a `git commit` and all went well. This has something to do with TortoiseGit but I am not sure what. It seems to choke on a large number of files or large directory depth.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error using Cygwin and git-svn. The solution that worked for me was to do garbage collection (odd as it seemed at the time):

```
$ git gc
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue, but I was able to commit with msysgit.  I updated tortoisegit, and also noticed that my msysgit version was not in sync with tortoise git.  I'm not sure if the latest version fixed it, or if it was due to having different versions of tortoise and msysgit.  Anyway, another thing to check.  It all started working after updating them both to 
TortoiseGit 1.7.10.0 
git version 1.7.10.msysgit.1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on macOS, I have solved it by removing `repo_folder/.git/index.lock`

Answer (score 0):

I used [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker) on `.git\index.lock` to unlock any handles that are held open by other processes.  In my case it was TGitCache.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using git in Windows 10, and this issue was resolved for me by clearing the system's temp directory.

As most replies here suggest, it's a disk-space related problem.